# Convolution in $L^2(-\pi ,\pi )$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm reading about the Fourier transform and it's properties in **The Spectral Analysis of Time Series - Koopmans, L.** and I found a particular statement that makes me feel a little bit skeptical.

Lets assume that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ belong to $L^2( -\pi ,\pi )$ and let $z=x*y$ where $*$ indicates the convolution. The author states that as a consequence of Schwartz inequality we have that $z(t)$ belongs to $L^2(-\pi ,\pi)$.

I know that [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) gives us a similar result but considering $L^1$, not $L^2$ and after a quick search in the site I found also some counterexamples of a similar statement (considering $L^2(R)$ ). So I would like to know if I am missing something, or the author is making further assumptions that I don't see.

Thanks.

Comment: It always holds that $||x*y||_2 \le ||x||_2 ||y||_1$. Since $(-\pi,\pi)$ is a finite measure space (unlike $\mathbb{R}$), the term $||x||_2 ||y||_1 \le ||x||_2 ||y||_2$ is finite.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_convolution_inequality

Comment: But isn't the norm-1 bigger than the norm-2?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think you're wrong. Take $p=2, r=2, q=1$ here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_convolution_inequality

Comment: @mathworker21 You are right. But the result doesn't require anything but  a simple application of Holder's inequality which proves that the convolution is bounded.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yea. also, cauchy-schwarz is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use $f,g$ for ease. I'll also assume they are real so that I don't have to conjugate stuff.

$$||f*g||_2^2 =\int |\int f(y)g(x-y)dy|^2 dx = \int \int \int f(y)g(x-y)f(z)g(x-z)dxdydz \le \int \int |f(y)||f(z)| (\int |g(x-y)|^2 dx)^{1/2}(\int |g(x-z)|^2 dx)^{1/2} dydz = \int \int |f(y)||f(z)| ||g||_2^2 \le ||f||_1^2||g||_2^2$$

Comment: is  the $||f||_1$ is a finite number? because I know that the $||f||_2$ is finite, and I also know that $||f||_1 \geq ||f||_2$.

Comment: @RamiroScorolli You have it backwards. $||f||_1 \le ||f||_2 < \infty$.

Comment: But, if you have a vector $x=(1,1)$ , $||x||_1=2$ while $||x||_2= \sqrt 2$

Comment: The inequality $||f||_1 \le ||f||_2$ holds in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. For "discrete" spaces such as vector spaces you are talking about, $||x||_1 \le ||x||_2$ is indeed false.

Comment: @RamiroScorolli does my answer make sense now?

Comment: Indeed it does, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $x(t)=\sum_k a_k\mathrm{e}^{ikx}$, then $\|x\|_{L^2}^2=\sum_k|a_k|^2$.

If $x(t)=\sum_k a_k\mathrm{e}^{ikx}$ and $y(t)=\sum_k b_k\mathrm{e}^{ikx}$, then
$(x*y)(t)=\sum_k c_k\mathrm{e}^{ikx}$, where $c_k=\sum_j a_jb_{k-j}$.

Hence
$$
\|x*y\|^2=\sum_k |c_k|^2=\sum_k\left|\sum_j a_jb_{k-j}\,\right|^2\le \sum_{k,j}|a_k|^2|b_j|^2=\|x\|^2\|y\|^2
$$

Comment: I don't quite understand what is going on here. Don't we get $\sum_k (\sum_j|a_j|^{2} \sum_j  |b_{k-j}|^{2}$? Isn't this $\infty $ except when one of the functions is $0$? @RamiroScorolli

Comment: Yea, I'm similarly confused by this solution

Answer (score 1):

Holder's inequality shows immediately that the convolution is bounded and any $L^{\infty}$ function is an $L^{2}$ function on a finite interval. Some details: $|\int f(x-y)g(y)\, dy| \leq \sqrt {\int |f(x-y)|^{2} \, dy}\sqrt {\int |g(y)|^{2} \, dy}$. Since $\sqrt {\int |f(x-y)|^{2} \, dy}=\sqrt {\int |f(y)|^{2} \, dy} $ for all $x$ we get $|(f*g)(x)| \leq \|f\|_2 \|g|_2$ for all $x$. Hence $f*g$ is a bounded measurable function. This implies that it is also in every $L^{p}$, in particular $L^{2}$.

Comment: is this because the $||f||_1$ is a finite number?

Comment: @RamiroScorolli I have included a detaild proof.